# Generate a list without accepting some values

Tags: python, python-2.7, random

I want to create a random list of tuples where each tuple is the same length (say 6 for example) and is made up of a random selection of `values = [0, 15, 30, 45, 60].`

An example solution would be `[(0, 30, 60, 0 , 15, 0)...(15, 45, 45, 0, 30, 60)]`. However, I don't want to accept `(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)` as a solution.

Comment: How many values do you want to generate?

Comment: So, in conclusion the summation of the whole tuple numbers cant be zero?

Comment: Please post some code that you have wrtten to try and solve the problem.  Refer to this article for help in writing a good Question: https://www.gamestorrento.com/?xb=http%3A%2F%2Ftorrentcounter.cc%2Ffiles%2Fdownload%2F8E4E6853F5E8DA448FBA3A94C9BD6C82C94AB8EC.torren

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just filter after the fact:

```
def random_nonzero_tuple(length=6, values=(0, 15, 30, 45, 60)):
    while True:
        tup = tuple(random.choice(values) for _ in range(length))
        if any(tup):
           return tup
```

`any(tup)` returns `False` if *all* values in `tup` are false; `0` is a false value. This guarantees the function never returns `(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0).

Use this in a list comprehension:

```
random_tuples = [random_nonzero_tuple() for _ in range(desired_length)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from random import choice

>>> from itertools import count

>>> from operator import itemgetter

>>> values = (0, 15, 30, 45, 60)

>>> length = 6

>>> non_zero_tuples_generator = filter (any, map (lambda _ : tuple (choice (values) for _ in range (length)), count ()))

>>> first_6_tuples = tuple (map (itemgetter (1), zip (range (6), non_zero_tuples_generator)))

((0, 60, 0, 60, 60, 60), (0, 45, 15, 60, 60, 30), (0, 0, 0, 0, 45, 30), (30, 15, 60, 30, 30, 60), (0, 30, 45, 0, 60, 30), (15, 60, 60, 0, 45, 60))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is:

```
from random import choice

def random_nonzero_tuple(length=6, values=(0, 15, 30, 45, 60)):
    tup = tuple(map(choice, (values,) * length))
    return tup if any(tup) else random_nonzero_tuple(length, values)
```

Comment: Although not that likely, this can lead to an infinite recursion exception if all you get is `(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)` tuples.